# docker run tomcat:latest connection timeout

Tags: docker, connection-timeout

Got "`ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`" when running docker for windows version: 
 `Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a.` 
 Using linux containers (default installation wizard settings).
Docker inspect containerID gives: `"IPAddress": "172.17.0.2"`, 
Network settings:

```
"NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "",
    "HairpinMode": false,
    "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
    "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "Ports": {
        "8080/tcp": null
```

State:

```
"State": {
    "Status": "running",
    "Running": true,
    "Paused": false,
    "Restarting": false,
    "OOMKilled": false,
    "Dead": false,
    "Pid": 2918,
    "ExitCode": 0,
    "Error": "",
```

Connecting to the docker tomcat with: http://172.17.0.2:8080
Error message: `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

No proxies in the docker settings.

[image]

Docker Logs containerID:

```
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.540 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.34
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.541 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 4 2018 22:28:22 UTC
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.541 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.34.0
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.542 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.542 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.9.93-linuxkit-aufs
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.542 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.542 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.542 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-1~deb9u1-b13
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.543 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.543 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.543 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.543 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.543 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.544 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.544 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.544 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.544 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.544 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.545 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.545 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.545 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.17] using APR version [1.5.2].
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.545 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.546 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.548 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017]
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.609 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.614 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.618 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.619 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.619 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 320 ms
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.630 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.631 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.34
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.652 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager]
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.835 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [182] ms
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.835 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.843 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [8] ms
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.844 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager]
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.854 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager] has finished in [10] ms
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.855 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs]
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.862 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs] has finished in [8] ms
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.862 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples]
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.965 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples] has finished in [103] ms
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.966 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.973 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
30-Sep-2018 19:44:54.974 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 355 ms
```

Comment: Have you looked at docker logs to see if there were any errors on startup of tomcat or checked inside the container if it's bound correctly to all interfaces?

Comment: @LucasHolt yes, I checked through it and no errors were logged. Just standard output and startup message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clearly saying that port mapping not done properly :

```
 "Ports": {
        "8080/tcp": null
  }
```

The `null` means the docker inside port 8080 has not mapped to it's corresponding in outside.

when port not mapped, there would not be any way you can access to it by url and you will get `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

as it's not clear how did you run your container I can only suggest you a simple and proper way of port mapping would be :

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 tomcat:latest
```

where 8080 outside port is mapped to inside docker tomcat 8080 port, then you can access it by localhost:8080

Comment: Right! Port was not correctly mapped and my port 8080 was blocked. Got it working with: `docker run -it --rm -p 9095:8080 tomcat:latest`

The correct port config should be something like this when running docker inspect containerID: 
            "Ports": {
                "8080/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "9095"
                    }
                ]
            },

And then accessing it from the web browser: `localhost:9095`

Comment: glad that it helped